# Creating a filtered Calendar display/showcase for upcoming Events

Tags: web-applications, calendar, google-calendar-api

At work we have a calendar in which we schedule who is coming in on what day (picture below). I want to create an webapp/website (run on an local server) that i can display on an old Ipad via the Browser. I only want to see the Entries with my name on it.
Is there an existing solution? (for local application or an existing website)
[google calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQgub.png)

I have searched the internet for existing solutions, found nothing usefull

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.